# Correlation Clustering for graph partitioning

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis, partitioning, image-segmentation

I am trying to do image segmentation by correlation clustering. I need to partition a graph. Is there a suitable library in matlab or python to implement this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked on this topic as part of my PhD research. You can find a few optimization algorithms [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html#LSCC). You might find that combining these optimization algorithms with a [multiscale framework](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.7070) can help both speeding up the run-time and improve the convergence of the optimization process.